How to include hyperlinked images in Word (.docx) output?
I'm using Quarto to generate documents that include hyperlinks in images. When I render my document to HTML, the images are correctly hyperlinked. However, when I render to Word (.docx), the images appear without the hyperlinks—they are not clickable.
Here's a minimal reproducible example:
Example rendering to html:
---
title: "Reproducible example to html"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| output: asis
cat('[![](img/elephant.png)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant)')
```

Example rendering to docx:
---
title: "Reproducible example to docx"
format: docx
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| output: asis
cat('[![](img/elephant.png)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant)')
```

In the HTML output, the image of the elephant is hyperlinked to the Wikipedia page for elephants, which is the expected behavior.
In the Word output, the image appears, but it is not hyperlinked—it is just a static image without any link.
My Goal:
I would like the images in the Word document to be hyperlinked so that when users click on the image, they are taken to the specified URL.
How can I produce an image with an embedded hyperlink when rendering to Word (.docx) using Quarto? Is there a way to ensure that hyperlinks on images are preserved in the Word output?

Maybe this link will help!
